# How to import a sudoku board in txt in Python?

Tags: python, sudoku

in one of my master degree classes I have to create in python a sudoku game (with special rules).
My professor request is that I need to import a .txt file with the sudoku board (for me created) to my code file.

I do like this:
**

```
def import_boardsudoku(filename):
    file=open(filename,'r')
    content=file.read()
    file.close()
    return content

    hs = []
    for line in content:
        hs_line = line.replace("\n"," ").split(",")
        hs.append(hs_line)

    for i in range(len(hs)):
        for j in range(len(hs[i])):
            if hs[i][j] == "0":
                hs[i][j] = " "
            else:
                hs[i][j]=int(hs[i][j])

    return hs
print import_boardsudoku("sudoku_hs.txt")
```

**

But I don´t understand:

1. Why my zeros don´t are replaced by whitespace
2. Why I can´t use my hs (boardsudoku imported) in the rest of my code (like print boardgame or validation of the rules, etc)

Inside my .txt file its:
[image: inside my .txt file its:]

Thank you very much for your help! :)

Comment: Please post your text file _as text!_ We cannot copy a screenshot. You can format it the same way you formatted your code. See the section on code blocks in [formatting help](/help/formatting)

Comment: Are you using python 2? Because if not, `print import_board...` is an error. Also, do you know about local variables and the scope of variables? You `return hs` from your function but never assign it to anything, so you lose it.

Comment: Even better, embed the text file in your code to create a [mcve]. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Hmm, did you notice that a `return` skips the rest of the function!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everything below

```
return content
```

is unusable as you are returning early.